# Use PHP to read an array of objects from Google Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

This seems like such a rookie question but I'm just banging my head against the keyboard here and I can't find anything answered already that gets me moving forward.

Scenario is I'm trying to get the Lat/Lng of a zip code by geocoding it with Google Maps API.  I've gotten the results back from Google Maps API as a JSON string and I've used json_decode to put it into a PHP array.  But it looks likt it's an array of objects and i'm stumped on how I can drill down into the data to get my lat/lng value.

Here is the current road block... code then results:

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"33647","short_name":"33647","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Tampa","short_name":"Tampa","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Florida","short_name":"FL","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Tampa, FL 33647, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":28.17150,"lng":-82.26235779999999},"southwest":{"lat":28.07291710,"lng":-82.42569910}},"location":{"lat":28.14343180,"lng":-82.33433749999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":28.17150,"lng":-82.26235779999999},"southwest":{"lat":28.07291710,"lng":-82.42569910}}},"types":["postal_code"]}],"status":"OK"}';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);

foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}
?>
```

Results:

```
stdClass Object ( [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [address_components] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [long_name] => 33647 [short_name] => 33647 [types] => Array ( [0] => postal_code ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [long_name] => Tampa [short_name] => Tampa [types] => Array ( [0] => locality [1] => political ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [long_name] => Florida [short_name] => FL [types] => Array ( [0] => administrative_area_level_1 [1] => political ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [long_name] => United States [short_name] => US [types] => Array ( [0] => country [1] => political ) ) ) [formatted_address] => Tampa, FL 33647, USA [geometry] => stdClass Object ( [bounds] => stdClass Object ( [northeast] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 28.1715 [lng] => -82.2623578 ) [southwest] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 28.0729171 [lng] => -82.4256991 ) ) [location] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 28.1434318 [lng] => -82.3343375 ) [location_type] => APPROXIMATE [viewport] => stdClass Object ( [northeast] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 28.1715 [lng] => -82.2623578 ) [southwest] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 28.0729171 [lng] => -82.4256991 ) ) ) [types] => Array ( [0] => postal_code ) ) ) [status] => OK )

results | Array

status | OK
```

URL used to create the input JSON:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=33647&sensor=false

Looking for some help to pull out the Lat and Long values out into a PHP variable.

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of results is in fact another array - so you need to dig into the array to get the values you need.

This page (http://json.parser.online.fr/) might help you to visualize the data a bit more clearly.

Here's a terrible example with your data to demonstrate the depth (arrays as values):

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"33647","short_name":"33647","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Tampa","short_name":"Tampa","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Florida","short_name":"FL","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Tampa, FL 33647, USA","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":28.17150,"lng":-82.26235779999999},"southwest":{"lat":28.07291710,"lng":-82.42569910}},"location":{"lat":28.14343180,"lng":-82.33433749999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":28.17150,"lng":-82.26235779999999},"southwest":{"lat":28.07291710,"lng":-82.42569910}}},"types":["postal_code"]}],"status":"OK"}';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData,true);
print_r($phpArray);

foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
    if ( $key == "results") {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                echo "<p>$key3 | $value3</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You'll need to dig down a couple of levels to find the ll data you want. This should point you in the right direction though.

Comment: Thanks Russ... this really did get me on the right path.  As another option, I dug a little deeper and found this which helped me dig down into the array or arrays :-)

$fullurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=33647&sensor=false";
$string = file_get_contents($fullurl); // get json content
$json_a = json_decode($string, true); //json decoder

echo $json_a['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
echo $json_a['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];